# Dropped network connections

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I've got a weird problem with my laptop that started a few days ago, it seems to be intermittent but seems to happen more in locations in the house which have low signal strength.

First I lose all connection to the router, windows still says that i'm connected to the network but says that access is limited. I can't access the router at this point or the internet.

If I disable and enable my WiFi adapter then I can reconnect again straight away, however if I try to disconnect and then reconnect again the network and sharing center locks up, I can't open up the list of WiFi networks near me, I can't open up the dialog to view the network adapters, if the list is already open then I can't enable or disable any devices on it. At this point I have to restart my PC in order to get back on the internet.

I initially thought it was the built in WiFi card not working, so I plugged in the external WiFi adapter that I use on my Desktop and after a while I got the same issue, my desktop does not suffer from this issue.

I'm using Windows 8 and my Desktop is running Windows 7. I'm using the Netgear Prosafe VPN client for work I've noticed the problem when connected to the VPN and disconnected.

EDIT: Most people that have the same issue as me have resolved it by turning off power saving on the WiFi adapter, however this has not fixed the issue for me.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."